# Как сделать, чтобы содержимое после каждой запятой внутри тега li переносило в новый li?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы содержимое после каждой запятой до ближайшей запятой внутри тега li переносило в новый li?
Чтобы из `<ul><li>один, два, три</li></ul>` получалось `<ul><li>один</li><li>два</li><li>три</li></ul>`, причем запятая убиралась?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А вот и нормальный способ:

```js
var ul = document.querySelector("ul")

var df = document.createDocumentFragment()

for (var li of ul.children) {
  for (var s of li.textContent.split(/\s*,\s*/)) {
    var x = document.createElement("li")
    x.textContent = s
    df.appendChild(x)
  }
}

ul.textContent = ""
ul.appendChild(df)
```

```html
<ul><li>один, два, три</li><li>4,5</li><li>777</li></ul>
```

Comment: это даже правильнее будет - + от меня

Answer (score 3):

Способ плохой, но если это не для сайта, то воспользоваться можно:

```js
var ul = document.querySelector("ul")
ul.innerHTML = ul.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, "<li>")
```

```html
<ul><li>один, два, три</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelectorAll("ul > li").forEach(function(li) {
  let words = li.textContent.split(/,\s*/);
  
  li.textContent = words[0];

  let new_html = words.slice(1).map(word => '<li>' + word + '</li>').join("");
  
  if( new_html ) li.insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", new_html);
});
```

```html
<ul><li>один, два, три</li><li>четыре</li></ul>
```

`/,\s*/` — `\s` англ. 'space', пробел. `*` — ноль или много штук.

Ну можно еще:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("ul > li").forEach(function(li) {
  let words = li.textContent.split(/,\s*/);
  
  li.outerHTML = words.map(word => '<li>' + word + '</li>').join("");
});
```

```html
<ul><li>один, два, три</li><li>четыре</li></ul>
```

Но он обновит тупо всё, даже если там не было запятых. Поэтому этот не нравится)

Comment: Этот вариант хуже моего. Если ты читаешь `textContent`, а пишешь в `innerHTML`, то это очевидная дыра для xss. Даже если ты просто делаешь что-то такое для того, чтобы удобнее прочитать текст и xss-атаки не ожидаются, есть значительная вероятность, что контент испортится.

Comment: Зря удалил, можно было добавить экранирование и стало бы лучше.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦ Или, оставлю так, чтобы было видно, как НЕ надо делать. Т.е. innerHTML / insertAndacentHTML всячески ннада избегать, заменяя на appendChild, insertAdjjacentElement, ага?)

Comment: Нет, не совсем так. А можешь задать отдельным вопросом - постараюсь подробно ответить?

Comment: @Qwertiy >> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1142971/xss-%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-innerhtml-insertadjacenthtml сделано.

Comment: [Ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1142977/178988).