# XSS-атаки: Что нужно использовать вместо innerHTML / insertAdjacentHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

В каких случаях можно смело добавлять HTML строкой, а когда нужно избегать такого подхода? И на что тогда заменить их?

Comment: Если источнику HTML-строки можно доверять, тогда и смело добавлять. Ваш кэп.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Исторически использовались шаблонизаторы, которые работали с разметкой, добавляя в неё некие данные, а потом вставляя через innerHTML. Так делалось из-за того, что парсинг html браузером работал быстрее, чем создание элементов из js. Про скорость обработки в актуальных браузерах сказать точно не могу, но современные фреймвёрки (например реакт и ангуляр) используют `createElement`. Ну и если задуматься - что должно быть быстрее - распарсить разметку, а потом создать элементы, или сразу создать элементы? Если очевидный ответ оказывается неверным, то это явное поле для оптимизации браузера.

В любом случае, в первую очередь стоит рассматривать не скорость работы, а корректность.

## О чём надо задуматься, работая с разметкой:

- Предполагается ли, что эти данные содержат разметку?
- Данные доверенные или могут быть получены от пользователей (в том числе через url, из внешних источников и т. д.)
- Как изменение разметки скажется на корректности работы страницы в плане скриптов?
- Уверены ли мы, что парсинг разметки приведёт к получению аналогичного dom-дерева?

## Разметка ожидается?

В большинстве случаев ответ на этот вопрос - нет.

Что будет с текстом, если его вывести как разметку? С обычным словом - ничего. Но если вдруг попадутся особые символы, то они пропадут. например, мы хотим вывести неравенство `a<b`, но браузер съест `<b` как начало тега и получившийся результат будет некорректен.

```html
Предположим, что a<b, тогда ...
```

И это даже с нейтральными текстами, целью которых не ставилось нанести сайту вред.

## Пользовательские данные

То, что вводит пользователь, не должно без дополнительной обработки превращаться в html-разметку. Есть два места, где этого не должно быть - на сервере при составлении кода страницы и на клиенте при вставке данных в разметку.

В случае сервера простор для инъекций огромный - можно просто записать `<script>alert(1)</script>` или закрыть пару лишних тегов и сломать разметку всей страницы, или попытаться закомментировать часть страницы, или просто через css спозиционировать ссылку на фишинговый сайт поверх лого, ведущего на главную сайта.

Если данные вставляются скриптом в `innerHTML`, то разметка не может выходить за рамки соответствующего элемента (однако тег `<style>` никто не отменял), а скрипт разместить чуть сложнее: `<img src="/no" onerror="alert(1)">`. Но по сути все те же атаки остаются возможны.

```js
document.querySelector('main').innerHTML = '<img src="/no" onerror="console.log(1)">'
```

```html
<main></main>
```

## Ломаем скрипты?

Что происходит, когда мы меняем разметку через `innerHTML`? Вся новая разметка парсится заново, создаются *новые* html-элементы - даже для той части, которая не менялась. Сразу очевидно, что это неэффективно, но есть проблемы покрупнее. Если скрипты повесили обработчики на какие-то элементы, то после обновления разметки обработчики останутся висеть на старых элементах, которых больше нет в dom-дереве. Поэтому при дополнении разметки стоит выбирать `insertAdjacentHTML`, а не `innerHTML +=`:

```js
document.getElementById('ih').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.parentElement.innerHTML += "<i></i>"
})

document.getElementById('ia').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<i></i>")
})

document.getElementById('ac').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.parentElement.appendChild(document.createElement('i'))
})
```

```css
i {
  display: inline-block;
  background: silver;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p><button id="ih">innerHTML</button></p>
<p><button id="ia">insertAdjacentHTML</button></p>
<p><button id="ac">appendChild</button></p>
```

## Ломаем разметку?

Любые манипуляции с `innerHTML` или dom-элементом не выходят за пределы этого элемента. Однако, если мы настроим чего-то хитрого, что получившееся дерево не является валидным, то после повторного парсинга можно сильно удивиться получившемуся результату:

```js
var oldP = document.querySelector('main p')

var newP = document.createElement('p')
newP.textContent = "456"
oldP.appendChild(newP)

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  var main = document.querySelector('main')

  console.log(main.innerHTML)
  main.innerHTML = main.innerHTML
  console.log(main.innerHTML)
})
```

```css
p p { color: blue; }
p + p { color: red; }
```

```html
<main><p>123</p></main>
<button>Ooops!</button>
```

## Когда использовать работу с разметкой?

- Мы знаем, что добавляем именно разметку, причём из доверенного источника.
- Если есть причины вставлять в разметку данные, то они должны соответствующим образом экранироваться, чтобы гарантированно остаться строкой, а не стать разметкой с элементами.
- Если мы хотим дополнить элемент разметкой, стоит предпочитать именно добавление разметки, а не полную перезапись.

## textContent и innerText

Свойство `textContent` позволяет легко вставлять произвольный текст в элемент и при этом браузер сам позаботится об экранировании. Если нам надо просто вставить текст, что бы туда не написал пользователь, это идеальный вариант:

```js
document.querySelector('main').textContent = '<img src="/no" onerror="console.log(1)">'
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Что касается свойства `innerText`, то его почти никогда не надо использовать. При записи оно ведёт себя так же, как `textContent`, но в некоторых случаях в десятки раз медленнее. При чтении оно отдаёт не весь текст, а только видимый - это можно использовать при необходимости, но такое требуется крайне редко. В стандарт его всё-таки включили.

```js
var main = document.querySelector('main')

console.log(main.textContent)
console.log(main.innerText)
```

```html
<main>
  <style>p { color: blue; }</style>
  <p>123</p>
  <p hidden>123</p>
  И немного
  текста
</main>
```

## Когда работать с элементами?

На мой взгляд - почти всегда кроме редких случаев, когда надо работать с разметкой. Браузер сам заботится об экранировании при использовании `textContent`, а при создании и вставке элементов они вставляются именно туда, куда мы хотим и не портят окружающий контент. Тут почти нереально накосячить со случайным закрытием тега не в том месте.

## Что почти наверняка является ошибкой?

- Помещение пользовательских или не доверенных данных в разметку.
- Чтение чего-либо из `textContent` и последующая запись в `innerHTML` - тут правило простое - откуда прочитали, туда и записали. Если перенос в любую сторону оказывается побочным эффектом (а не намеренным понимаемым действием), то он как минимум ломает отображение данных, а как максимум - создаёт уязвимость на сайте. Да и вообще, все манипуляции над разметкой как строкой надо выполнять осторожно.
- Использование `+=` на `innerHTML`.

Также нежелательна слишком частая работа с dom-элементами, находящимися в докумменте. Вставка элемента в документ после завершения работы над ним может дать существенное улучшение производительности. Если надо вставить группу элементов, то можно использовать document fragment.

## Мне только допилить страницу у себя

Бывает, что код пишется не для сайта, а для того, чтобы совершенно чужую страницу привести к пригодному для печати виду. Какие правила стоит продолжить соблюдать, а какие нет?

Тут можно легче отнестись к производительности и поломке скриптов, но перенос текста в разметку всё равно потенциально ломает данные в неожиданных местах и этого всё ещё стоит избегать. Скрипты из тегов `<script>` не исполнятся, а вот инлайновые обработчики событий иногда могут удивить, хотя на современных сайтах их обычно нет.

Answer (score 4):

Можно:

- Использовать HTML пришедший с родного или доверенного сервера, который создавали админы и разработчики;
- HTML который конструировался на сервере из пользовательских данных.

Нельзя:

- Конструировать HTML-контент на клиенте перед отправкой на сервер для хранения;
- Пропускать проверку на наличие HTML-тегов пользовательских данных.

Схема создания пользователем HTML-контента примерно такая:

1. Пользователь видит конструктор контента (как тут, на StackOverflow) и заполняет нужные поля, использует доступные инструменты;
2. Форма отправляет данные не генерируя каких-либо тегов. Можно, к примеру, использовать JSON: `{ title: "", body: "" ... }`;
3. Сервер выполняет проверку и очистку полученных данных. Любые (или только опасные) HTML-теги должны быть выброшены, а скрипт без тегов уже больше похож не на скрипт, а на текст;
4. Сервер конструирует HTML-строку и сохраняет в БД.

Таким образом за счёт хороших проверки и конструктора на стороне сервера, пользовательский HTML тоже становится доверенным.

Comment: _"Пропускать проверку на наличие HTML-тегов пользовательских данных."_ - нужна не проверка, а правильный вывод - они должны просто превратиться в текст.

Comment: Почему же, иногда я хочу, чтобы мне пришел именно кусок html, который я таки отображу браузером.

Comment: А вообще иногда код нужно превращать и в текст, как например тут: `<script src="tryToXSS.js"></script>`. Ну вот, похоже код не работает(

Comment: У каждого проекта свои требования! Но в любом случае пропускать пользовательский html, а затем рисовать его без проверок и обработок не следует.