# Добавление CSS через JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css3

у меня такой вопрос, мне нужно применить CSS свойство `filter: invert(100%);` ко всем элементам `*` и убрать его, каким образом это можно сделать через JS (без использывания jQueri)

Comment: Вы делаете что-то неправильное. В любом случае, просто создайте `style` элемент с необходимым содержимым, после чего удалите его из документа при необходимости

Comment: А что будет, если вместо перебора всего и вся, просто повесить фильтр на body?) `document.body.style.filter = "invert(100%)";`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, не, эффект у `invert`'a разный будет

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Хмм, даже просто `<style> * { filter: invert(100%) } </style>` - на этой странице хром перекрашивает всё тупо в черный, не справляется.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, навесить на все invert - очень затратная операция. Потому что вы инвертируете элемент, потом его родитель заново его инвертирует, потом родитель его родителя инвертирует его снова и так далее.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, эффект разный, а вот какой из них желаемый - я бы поставил под вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну, у ТС глаза-то есть. Для него работает отдельное навешивание. Но это действительно что-то очень странное

Answer (score 9, accepted):

По  аналогии, вместо `color` - `filter`, и нужное значение.

```js
// Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*')).map(e => e.style.color = 'green'); - плохой вариант, т.к. будет три копии массива с елементами
for (const e of document.querySelectorAll('*')) {
  e.style.color = 'green';
}
```

```html
<p style="color: blue;">Text</p>
<p style="color: red;">Text</p>
```

Либо так:

```js
const s = document.createElement('style');
s.textContent = '* { color: green !important; }';
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

```html
<p style="color: red;">Text</p>
<p style="color: blue;">Text</p>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112141/discussion-on-answer-by-entithat--css--javascript).

Comment: Эм.. `innerText`...

Comment: @Qwertiy, стоит использовать `textContent`?

Comment: @entithat, для другого тега я бы сказал да, но конкретно для style и script вроде бы были нюансы в зависимости от браузера. Там ещё и innerHTML среди вариантов. Так что точно не знаю, надо искать и проверять.

Comment: @Qwertiy, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12201713/7791165. Ага, это за script.

Comment: @entithat, 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1142977/178988 2. Ну так они невидимые - если сделать видимыми, должен вернуть, иначе это очень странно. 3. У тебя запись, а не чтение.