# Почему не срабатывает xss?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

Я написал два варианта одного и того же кода. Суть в том, что пользователь вводит в поле типа input вредоносный код:

```
<script>alert('xss attack')</script>
```

В результате jquery-код выполняет команду alert. А nativeJS-код не выполняет.

```js
$('#btn1').on('click', () => {
  const val = $('#inp1').val();
  $('#root1').append(val);
});

// ---

const inp2 = document.getElementById('inp2');
const btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
const root2 = document.getElementById('root2');

btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  root2.innerHTML += inp2.value;
});
```

```css
div script {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="inp1" value="<script> alert('xss-attack') </script>">
<button id="btn1">test</button>
<div id="root1"></div>

<hr>

<input id="inp2" value="<script> alert('xss-attack') </script>">
<button id="btn2">test</button>
<div id="root2"></div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста сделать так чтобы nativeJS-код тоже выполнял команду alert. Не обязательно использовать innerHTML.

Я пробовал вместо innerHTML использовать createElement/createTextNode , но тоже не получилось. Хотя jquery-метод использует именно их, судя по исходникам

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1142977/178988

Answer (score 5):

По стандарту при вставке разметки скрипты не выполняются, надо делать так:

```
<img src="/qqq" onerror="alert('xss attack')">
```

Вот запускаемый пример:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = `<img src="/qqq" onerror="alert('xss attack')">`
```